# Sum of fractions given sum of denominators and count

Tags: fractions, summation-method

I am summing the reciprocal values of a range of integers.

ex.

2,6,4

would give:

Result =$\frac{1}{2}$+$\frac{1}{6}$+$\frac{1}{4}$ = $\frac{11}{12}$

**My question**
Could I arrive at the same result given just the sum of the integers (12) and the number of integers (3)?

From the place where I am to do the calculation, that is the only two pieces of information that I have available right now.

Sorry if its super obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,if we take $3,4,5$ then $3+4+5=12$ but
$$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{20+15+12}{60}=\frac{47}{60}\neq\frac{11}{12}$$

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. The fact that other ranges with different values has the same sum proves that its not possible. This is exactly what I needed to know!